# MySQL - INTERVAL with DECIMAL for MONTH and YEAR does not work

Tags: mysql, decimal, intervals

I am using MySQL 5.6.12 and I have to add 1.5 MONTH to a date (I cannot add 45 days as it has to be month specific). 
Even if I CAST it to DECIMAL(2,1), as recommended in the documentation, it rounds it up to 2. The specific instruction is:

DATE_ADD(index_date, INTERVAL CAST(1.5 AS DECIMAL(2,1)) MONTH)

I tried with 1.4 MONTH and it rounds it down to 1.
I have tried with YEAR and the problem is the same.
I have also tried with MySQL 5.7.9, no difference.

Any suggestions?
Many thanks!

Comment: I am using MySQL 5.7.18 and this works for me `SELECT DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL CAST(1.5 AS DECIMAL(2,1)) MONTH);`  What is `index_date`?  may issue there?

Comment: I tried your select, but it does not work for me. Maybe they fixed the problem in later versions as you use version 5.7.18.

Comment: index_date is a date

Comment: Does this work `SELECT DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH);`  ?

Comment: Yes, it does. The decimal is the problem, your previous select gives me this answer 2017-08-08 19:39:22 where 2 month are added instead of 1.5

Comment: Oh I am sorry, I thought you meant you had a syntax error.  I guess it takes the the integer value only.

Comment: Please provide a formula for 1.5 months that is "month specific".  Then show how it should be added to Jan 5 or Jan 25.

Comment: Formula = SELECT index_date, DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(index_date, INTERVAL DAY(LAST_DAY(index_date)) DAY), 
INTERVAL DAY(LAST_DAY(DATE_ADD(index_date, INTERVAL DAY(LAST_DAY(index_date)) DAY)))/2 DAY)
from _patient;

Comment: 5 Jan + 1.5 MONTH = 19/02/2017
25 Jan + 1.5 MONTH = 11/03/2017

Comment: I don't know what 'month specific' means (and neither does MySQL). Specific to the current month or the next month?

Answer (score 1):

The `INTERVAL` function only works for integral values.

As a workaround, convert "1.4" months into some number of days.  Use `ROUND` or `FLOOR` or `CEILING` to turn it into an integer, then

```
+ INTERVAL ... DAY
```

should give you want you need.

Or if you need `SECOND` precision, then do a slightly different formula.

Or if you need millisecond, ... (etc)

Notice that the formula changes depending on the precision you desire.  For that reason it does not make sense for MySQL to define fractional values of a Month or Year.